# Why does W1022 warning showed in x86, but not in x64?

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, windows-11, delphi-11-alexandria

My delphi is 11 Ver.28.0.47991.2819.

When the below simple code was compiled in x64 (Target platform 64bit),  no warning occurred.
But for x86 (Target platform 32bit), shows `W1022 Comparison always evaluates to True`.

Variable `a` is `Unsigned`, so I feel it's correct in the x86 one.
Why is the warning not shown while compiling for x64?

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
    a : NativeUInt;
begin
    a := 1;
    if ( 0 <= a ) then begin
        Caption := IntToStr( a );
    end;
end;
```

I feel nothing special while checking assembly code.

```
Unit1.pas.73: if ( 0 <= a ) then begin
0000000001142444 48837D3800       cmp qword ptr [rbp+$38],$00
0000000001142449 7227             jb TForm1.FormCreate + $52
```

Thanks.

Comment: Submit a bug report to Embarcadero.

Comment: I tried to post to Embarcadero, but it was failed. I'll try it later, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the check leading to the W1022 is only performed on 32-bit ordinals. Change the type of `a` to `Cardinal` and you get the warning also on x64.

Comment: (In German "Obviously" = [offensichtlich](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/offensichtlich) suffers often from incorrect usage as synonym for [scheinbar](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/scheinbar) = "apparently". A typical case for [false friends](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falscher_Freund#Beispiele) is "_When do I become my Schnitzel?_")